# Shared Objects in Flash to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have found a bunch of online games with high-score saving, and the documentation says `Game settings and highscores saved to Shared Objects`. What does this means?

Is it possible to catch that "shared objects" from Flash in Javascript?

I have searched on Google regarding this, but cannot find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: You would use Flash to read the SharedObject then send that to Javascript via [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Comment: pretty sure he means to catch and hack into the data used by the games he refers to. This is not a how to question but a how to hack question.

Answer (score 0):

[SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) is as flash storage similar to browser cookies. Usage example:

```
// creating and setting
var mySharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("settings"); //retrieve object or create if not exists
mySharedObject.data.sound = 10;
mySharedObject.data.nickname = "John";
mySharedObject.flush();

// getting
var mySharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("settings");
trace(mySharedObject.data.sound);
trace(mySharedObject.data.nickname);
```

You can pass SharedObject data through [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html). It is very simple to use:

```
ExternalInterface.call("yourJSFunctionName", mySharedObject.data);
```